# How to delete values between xml tags in Vi editor

Tags: vim, vi

I want to replace the value between below xml tags in VI for all the columns ending with AM

```
<property name="EQ_BNKCRD_30PL_DPD_BAL_AM" desc="EQ_BNKCRD_30PL_DPD_BAL_AM">+000026928134473.000</property>
```

simply +000026928134473.000 should be removed in the above tags

I have tried `:%s/_AM">*.*</_AM"></g`

but the output is this

```
<property name="EQ_RVLV_TRD_OPN_HI_LC_AM"><property>
```

from the above the desc part is removed and in property tag / is removed

Answer (score 5):

```
dit
```

in normal mode, which means delete inside tag. If you do 'dat' delete around tag it would delete the tag too.

Answer (score 0):

You want to match everything from `_AM">` up to the next `<`. So this should work:

```
:%s/_AM">[^<]*</_AM"></g
```

The important change is from `>*.*` (which doesn't actually make much sense as it matches any number of `>` symbols and then anything after) to `>[^<]*` which means match one `>` and then anything that isn't a `<`.

Answer (score 0):

how about :

```
%s/_AM">\zs[^<]*//
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to use a macro in this case. To delete the contents in between tags you can use `dit`. The following sets the search register to `_AM>` and just looks for the next match  types `dit` every time it finds a match.

```
let @/='_AM">' | let @a='ndit@a' | set nowrapscan
```

Then go to the top of the file `gg` and run the macro that was stored in register a with `@a`. `set nowrapscan` is necessary to make sure the macro never goes on forever.

Answer (score 0):

Why not record a macro that searches for the next occurrence of `AM">`, move the cursor a few characters to the right into the tag, and then `dit` for "Delete In Tag" -- then just play it back a ton of times

I often find it faster in cases like this to record a simple macro rather than taking the time to find a regex that works.

Edit: full sequence, separated logically

```
/AM">
qa
llll
dit
n
q
500@a
```